writing to memory allocated with mmap fails in x86 Assembly
I am currently trying to teach myself Assembly on a x86 Linux machine with the NASM assembler and ld linker. As of right now I am attempting to understand the mmap syscall.
To do this I wrote this very simple code here, but it breaks for some reason that I do not understand.
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 9      ;mmap syscall
    mov rsi, 2      ;length in bytes
    mov rdx, 3      ;read and write permissions
    mov r8, -1      ;fill with 0s
    mov r9, 0       ;no offset
    mov r10, 0x22   ;private and anonymous memory
    syscall

    mov ax, "hi"    ;define string
    mov [rdi], ax   ;write string to memory (fails for some reason)

    mov rsi, rdi
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall         ;print string

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall         ;end program

When I try to run this code, it terminates with a Segmentation Fault.
I have tried removing the two lines where I write to the allocated memory and in that case I do not get any errors, so it's the writing to memory part that fails.
As I am very new to Assembly this is probably a very stupid mistake on my part, but I'd still appreciate any advice
The updated (working) code:
section .text
   global _start

_start:
   mov rax, 9      ;mmap syscall
   mov rdi, 0      ;not passing any pointer
   mov rsi, 2      ;length in bytes
   mov rdx, 3      ;read and write permissions
   mov r8, -1      ;fill with 0s
   mov r9, 0       ;no offset
   mov r10, 0x22   ;private and anonymous memory
   syscall

   mov bx, "hi"    ;define string
   mov [rax], bx   ;write string to memory

   mov rsi, rax
   mov rax, 1
   mov rdi, 1
   mov rdx, 2
   syscall         ;print string

   mov rax, 60
   mov rdi, 0
   syscall         ;end program


Linux system calls return a value in rax, not rdi.

I vaguely recall that mmap might have a special calling convention, where you put the arguments into a structure in memory and then pass a pointer. But I can't easily check right now.

If it is the usual register calling convention, then you still need to zero out rdi to indicate that the kernel chooses the address. I don't think you can rely on rdi being zero on entry to your program.

Try it in C, get it working and then see what the compiler does.

@NateEldredge First of all, thank you for your answer. At least according to this table it seems to be the correct convention for the registers. I tried replacing rdi with rax and zeroing out rdi, but I still get a SegFault.

Did you also replace the ax? Because that's part of rax so you will overwrite the result. Anyway you can do mov word [rax], "hi". Works here.

Please update your question with the exact code you are now using. If you just describe your changes in words in the comments, then we can't really tell exactly what you're doing or if all necessary changes have been made correctly.

@Jester I did forget to change the ax. It works now
